# Thinking Sphinx - Sort by decimal fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm running thinking-sphinx 3.1.0 and rails 3.2.13 with MySQL 14.14.

I'm trying to sort the results by a price field. The index looks like:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :book, :with => :active_record do
 indexes authors.title, :as => :title
 indexes price, :sortable => true, :as => :price, :type => :float
end
```

It sorts like this:

```
0.00
10.95
12.95
5.00
6.5
9.95
```

Looks like it keeps treating the price field as a string rather than a float or a decimal. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `indexes` method is for defining Sphinx fields - which are always string data (from a Sphinx perspective anyway, whether or not they're strings in your database).

A Sphinx attribute is a far more reliable option in this case, as has the ability to have a float data type, and are sortable by their very nature. These are defined using the `has` method:

```
indexes authors.title, :as => :title
has price, :type => :float
```

You do not need the `:sortable` option (because all attributes are sortable), nor the `:as` option (because you're referencing a column directly and not changing the name). The `:type` option may not even be needed if the underlying database column type is a float or a decimal - in those two situations, Thinking Sphinx will automatically set the type to `:float` for you.